# Find the central point in each Sierpinski triangle

Tags: list-manipulation, fractals

I'm trying to do something like this for higher orders.

[image]

What I've done is using a code available on internet to generate the Sierpinski points, and then TriangleCenter to obtain the medium points but in a manual way. For l=4, for example, this become very tedious to do manually

```
sierpinski[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  With[{ab = (a + b)/2, bc = (b + c)/2, 
    ca = (a + c)/2}, {{a, ab, ca}, {ab, b, bc}, {ca, bc, c}}];

pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}} // N;
l = 2;
d = Nest[Join @@ sierpinski /@ # &, {pts}, 
  l]; 

SGg = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[Flatten[d, 1]]];

(*L=1*)
(*MEDIUM={TriangleCenter[{SGg[[1]],SGg[[2]],SGg[[3]]},"Centroid"],\
TriangleCenter[{SGg[[3]],SGg[[5]],SGg[[6]]},"Centroid"],\
TriangleCenter[{SGg[[2]],SGg[[4]],SGg[[5]]},"Centroid"]};*)

(*L=2*)
MEDIUM = {TriangleCenter[{SGg[[1]], SGg[[2]], SGg[[3]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[3]], SGg[[5]], SGg[[7]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[7]], SGg[[10]], SGg[[12]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[14]], SGg[[15]], SGg[[12]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[2]], SGg[[4]], SGg[[5]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[10]], SGg[[13]], SGg[[14]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[4]], SGg[[6]], SGg[[8]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[8]], SGg[[11]], SGg[[13]]}, "Centroid"], 
   TriangleCenter[{SGg[[6]], SGg[[9]], SGg[[11]]}, "Centroid"]};

SG = Union[SGg, MEDIUM];
```

How could I optimize this?

Comment: The question arises: what for?

Comment: even the simplest way `TriangleCenter[SGg[[{3,5,7}]], "Centroid"]`

Comment: then `TriangleCenter[SGg[[#]], "Centroid"] &/@{{1,2,3},{3,5,7}}` etc.

Comment: Hmm this is pretty cool. If I SortBy Last, and make a list Table[{i,i+1,i+17},{i,1,16}] for l=4 it works well for the first line.

Comment: I see two options:  (1) Analyze the iterated construction of sierpinski and modify it to handle the nested triangles (1,3,9,27,...)  as they are created, or (2)  Write your own routine:  start with just one triangle, get mid points, then construct the next level of three triangles, get midpoints,  then for each of these, construct the nine interior triangles of each of those and so on.  I think (2) is best way to go although will take some time.

Comment: maybe something like  `SierpinskiMesh[4, 2, MeshCellShapeFunction -> {2 -> ({Polygon@#, Red,  Point[RegionCentroid@Polygon@#]} &)}]`?

Comment: How do I get the x,y coordinates from these points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret your code correctly, then d contains the coordinates of the vertices of all triangles. To start from there, you may map "TriangleCenter" onto d and then apply "Point" to the result.

Further. To draw the triangles, you may either map "Triangle" on d:

```
l = 3;
d = Nest[Join @@ sierpinski /@ # &, {pts}, l];
Graphics[{Green, Triangle /@ d, Red, Point[TriangleCenter /@ d]}]
```

[image]

Or you may draw the polygon that makes up the triangle. However, for this you need to add the last stroke that closes the triangle:

```
Graphics[{Line@Append[#, #[[1]]] & /@ d, Point[TriangleCenter /@ d]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One way is to retrieve the [`MeshCellCentroid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellCentroid.html) property for each [`SierpinskiMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SierpinskiMesh.html) cell.

```
mesh = SierpinskiMesh[3];

centers = AnnotationValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];

Show[mesh, Graphics[Point[centers]]]
```

[image]

---

Per the comments, we can get exact centers by injecting an undocumented option into `MeshRegion`. As with anything undocumented, no promises that this will work in future versions.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{MeshRegion},
  Unprotect[MeshRegion];
  MeshRegion[args__] /; FreeQ[{args}, WorkingPrecision -> _, {1}] := 
     MeshRegion[args, WorkingPrecision -> ∞];

  mesh = SierpinskiMesh[3];
]

centers = AnnotationValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];

centers[[1 ;; 3]]
```

> ```
> {{1/16, 1/(16 Sqrt[3])}, {3/16, 1/(16 Sqrt[3])}, {1/8, 1/(4 Sqrt[3])}}
> ```

Comment: Can you automatically generate exact coordinates rather then approximated ones? E.g. the "first" point should be `{1/16, 1/(16 Sqrt[3])}`.

Comment: @Artes see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, nice (+1), although I prefer  a more specific approach not relying on internal "hacks".

Comment: With this edit I could get the {x,y} points thanks! But the solution given by Daniel Huber was right under my nose and I didnt saw it! I got surprised.